# jQuery selector with variables in each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help because I can't find what I'm doing in the wrong way. I have this code:

datosPre used at each is like:

```
datosPre[0]='TipoViaFact=Paseo';
datosPre[1]='ProvinciaFact=3';

 $.each(datosPre, function(key, value) {
            var tempArray = value.split('=');
            if (tempArray[0] == 'TipoViaFact' || tempArray[0] == 'ProvinciaFact') {
                 var tx0 =tempArray[0].toString();
                  console.log(tx0);
                 var tx1 =tempArray[1].toString();        
                  console.log(tx1);
                  console.log("selector:"+"[name="+tx0+"] option[value="+tx1+"]");
                 var txs =$("[name='"+tx0+"'] option[value="+tx1+"]").text();
                //$("[name='"+tx0+"'] option[value="+tx1+"]").attr('selected','selected');
                  console.log(txs);
            } 
 });
```

`console.log(txs)` returns `empty` string. I'm using `.text()` to test, but I need the selector to add "`.attr('selected','selected');`" instead of `.text();`

I have tried using Firebug console to replace myself the vars at txs selector and it works, but not here.

I'have read several post here and I'have followed the examples to do that at this way.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why don't you just debug this? It'll be far easier for you to compare the results with HTML (which you didn't show in this question).

Comment: Note that if you're free to choose the format to store the preselected data (which you seem to do), it's beneficial to use JS Object instead of array of strings, like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P9k6q/).

Comment: Finally, you do invoke this when DOM is loaded, right? Because otherwise it's rather trivial problem.

Comment: @raina77ow first of all, thank you for your help.

Comment: The original data is a string that contains information in format key=value. I'm debugging since 2 hours ago. the DOM IS LOADED, right. I only have problems with select-option, the input type text works with :  $("input[name='" + tempArray[0] + "']").val(tempArray[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var datosPre = new Array();
datosPre[0]='TipoViaFact=Paseo';
datosPre[1]='ProvinciaFact=3';

 $.each(datosPre, function(key, value) {
            var tempArray = value.split('=');
            if (tempArray[0] == 'TipoViaFact' || tempArray[0] == 'ProvinciaFact') {
                 var tx0 =tempArray[0].toString();
                  console.log(tx0);
                 var tx1 =tempArray[1].toString();        
                  console.log(tx1);
                  console.log("selector:"+"[name="+tx0+"] option[value="+tx1+"]");
                 var txs =$("[name='"+tx0+"'] option[value="+tx1+"]").text();
                //$("[name='"+tx0+"'] option[value="+tx1+"]").attr('selected','selected');
                  console.log(txs);
            } 
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around `value` attribute value in selector.try this.

```
     var txs =$("[name='"+tx0+"'] option[value='"+tx1+"']").text();
     console.log(txs);
```

and to select that option:

```
     $("[name='"+tx0+"'] option[value='"+tx1+"']").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: The quotation marks are not required if `tx0` and `tx1` are valid identifiers - and in the first case they are.

Comment: @raina77ow:does that mean its not gonna appear in both name-value selector??

Comment: @raina77ow it's right, I've tryied with quotes and without quotes and I've get the same result.